# PHP: Fatal Error Call to a member function ... on a non-object

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with PHP as it keeps throwing the Exception mention in the title.
It fails on the following line:

```
$item->getDescription();
```

I understand what the error should mean (`$item` is null). However, $item is not null.

The scenario is as follows:
This is a script that syncs products from a supplier to a store. For that purpose, I have created my own class (SimpleProduct). This class has a getDescription() function.

The problem is that the data I'm receiving tend to have a lot of garbage, like items that haven't been filled in yet. The script should skip these items and keep on iterating across the rest of the products.
This fatal error kills the entire script.

I've already tried implementind safeguards to prevent this from happening, but it still occurs constantly. Here's the current code (some snippets removed as they arent pertinent to the currect case).

```
//This is part of a class that performs the sync

public function syncProduct($item) {

    if(empty($item)) { return "Not a product"; }
         else { var_dump($item) }

    $foo = $item->getDescription();
}
```

When checking the var_dump result, I get an object with some values filled in. Seeing as it is of the correct type (SimpleProduct) and it is not empty/null, I would suspect this error to stop occurring, but it still does.

Also note that several product syncs have already occurred without any errors before this one pops up, so I know the code is valid. Somehow, this specific case slips past my null-checks.

Is my null-check faulty?
How can an error for a non-object be thrown when the object in question does exist?

Comment: can you post the var_dump output?

Comment: if you do a var_dump() before the if(), for all $items, do you see the offending $item type?

Comment: In that case only reason I can see is getDescription() method is throeing that error .. can you please pase code for getDescription() method

Comment: You're saying the var_dump occurs, are you sure it's not a var_dump for the previous value - assuming you're processing multiple products not just one? To make sure it's not the var_dump of the previous value take the var_dump out of the if/else, put it before the if - this way you'll see the non-object values that trigger the error.

Comment: Copy/Pasting doesn't work as the machine I'm using is abroad, stupid bug :( However, I can confirm that the var_dump() shows me the correct fields, because I also get the var_dump for all previous, CORRECT, entries. Those results have exactly the same form. It is my SimpleProduct class.

Comment: Using an incorrect and/or complex SQL`SELECT` statement can produce NULL values. Also this error could be triggered even lower down in your code - after this function executes correctly another may expect one of the properties of the $item object to be objects.

Comment: I would also check if it is_object() really. O course the var_dump() output would help here most :)

Comment: Not using a SELECT, my code creates the objects and builds its own array. I read the results for the supplier's SOAP client, then I convert is to simpleproducts, and at this stage i'm converting those products to SOAPcalls to the webstore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of checking whether if the variable is empty, why not check whether if it's an instance of `SimpleProduct`?

```
if ($item instanceof SimpleProduct)
{

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php

Comment: That check is actually executed in the code above, the above function only gets called if it validates against the SimpleProduct type.

Comment: Well i'll be.... I added that check again in the function and now it succeeds. I have no idea why it only works of the check is in the same function rather that right before calling it, but it works (well, I get other errors now but they are unrelated to this case).

Comment: In this case I'd add a debug_backtrace() in the `if ( !instanceof )` branch and check whether there is another caller.

Answer (score 0):

Your null check is not preventing the object to be used even if it <strike>is null</strike> contains non-objects.

Use this:

```
public function syncProduct($item) {
    var_dump($item);

    if($item InstanceOf SimpleProduct) {
        $foo = $item->getDescription();
    }

    return "Not a product";
}
```

I stand corrected! I didn't notice the return statement. The other case for this to occur would be if the value from `$item` would be non-empty but not a product either - most likely a scalar or array because using objects as other types of objects issue a different error regarding methods not being found.

Comment: If it is empty, the function returns the string 'Not a product', why should it execute code that it encounters after a return statement? The code is part of a larger iteration and I'm actually already 7-8 levels of code nesting deep, so I'd prefer to not add an extra layer (for readability). Shouldn't this solution be the same becase there is a return statement in the if-block?

Answer (score 0):

Surely the object is still not available in the context of the function syncProduct.

Try to do a var_dump($item) to confirm its there and execute it within the else part of the code to ensure its not empty.

Comment: Check the code, it does execute a var_dump. That's the weird part. The var_dump occurs (therefore the object is not empty, see the if-statement). Also, the var_dump return a valid object, yet I get an error that that same object is null.

Answer (score 0):

To check if $item is an object You can use [is_object()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php)

Comment: This doesn't really take care of the error completely. What if the variable is an object but doesn't have the `getDescription` method implemented?

Comment: Yea I realised that when I saw your solution. Not got enough reputation points to upvote it though :(

Answer (score 0):

I also run into a similar problem where after running this:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->action($action="SELECT * ", 'users');
```

Then checking whether $user is an instance of DB, I found that it wasn't. I then decided separate it as follows:

```
$user = DB::getInstance();
$user->action($action="SELECT * ", 'users');
```

After doing this and using instanceof() method it shows that it is now an instance and the fatal call to member function error disappears.